# Local path in variable names in vendor.js when using Angular 14

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I recently updated to Angular 14. When building the app in development mode a vendor.js is created as expected and everything is working fine.
Inspecting this  file I see generated variable names reflecting the absolute path on my computer (my source is located in "C:\src"). I did not see this behaviour in earlier versions of Angular (12 and 13).

Some extract of vendor.js:

```
/*!****************************************************************!*\
  !*** ./node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/InnerSubscriber.js ***!
  \****************************************************************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {
/* harmony export */   "InnerSubscriber": () => (/* binding */ InnerSubscriber)
/* harmony export */ });
/* harmony import */ var C_src_MyApp_node_modules_babel_runtime_helpers_esm_classCallCheck_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/classCallCheck.js */ 8069);
/* harmony import */ var C_src_MyApp_node_modules_babel_runtime_helpers_esm_createClass_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/createClass.js */ 8047);
/* harmony import */ var C_src_MyApp_node_modules_babel_runtime_helpers_esm_inherits_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/inherits.js */ 4582);
/* harmony import */ var C_src_MyApp_node_modules_babel_runtime_helpers_esm_createSuper_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/createSuper.js */ 2496);
/* harmony import */ var _Subscriber__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./Subscriber */ 14);
```

If the source path is changed, the variable names will change accordingly.

Is there any configuration option, in angular.json or some other place, to affect the naming of these variables? I want to have these names independent from the absolute source path, so that other developers in my team can create the exact same file even if they use another source path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project, original tsconfig.json target setting is "ES5", change to "ES6" can solve this problem, these babel runtime helpers was no longer being import.

---

[@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/presets/application.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/774e83df8b6c7d854881519c46458f73994f0dc0/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/babel/presets/application.ts#L244)

Just because angular devkit config babel runtime transform runtime plugin with `absoluteRuntime: ${absolutePath}` when transform code to es5.

Comment: Eventually I used a similar approach by limiting the supported browsers in the .browserslistrc config file. This also solves the problem. Thanks for pointing me to this absoluteRuntime setting.